# What's a simple data set to to try clustering algorithms on?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, python, unsupervised-learning

I'm very new to Machine Learning and programming. I'm trying to run clustering algorithms on data sets but all examples I find contains lot of data and it confuses me. Can you give me a simple sample data, maybe a set of 2d-vectors, which I can prove the algorithms with and see how they work?

Update: It would be very helpful if the examples are in python

Comment: You may want to ask for data at [OpenData.SE](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @StephanKolassa I think this question is not about obtaining open data set so it is not relevant on the Open Data site. I see this the similarity between this kind of questions and the questions about books. So I would say that it is appropriate to ask on the CV site.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using R, it includes the `iris` dataset, which has three classes with four variables but if you want you can use only the Petal measurements to only have two dimensions. Of the three classes, one is well-separated from the other two and the two overlap.

Note: in just two dimensions, they literally overlap -- there are duplicate points. So some algorithms may prefer a little bit of noise added (use R's `jitter`). For experiments where I want only two classes, I'll keep Virginica and Versicolor (I'm pretty sure those are the two that overlap) if I want something not clear-cut, or keep one of those two plus Setosa for a clear delineation between the two.

(Of course, for clustering, you won't be using the Species (class) except to check your answers.)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of data sets that come with installed R packages. A commonly used one (4 numerical variables and 1 categorical variable) is the `iris` data set.

If you look at the help documentation of the `cluster` R package, there are some useful ones there as well!

Answer (score 0):

The first dataset I thought was also 'iris,' although 'old faithful' is also extremely common in demonstrations of clustering.

And while iris does have more than two dimensions, here is what I found (from an experiment that involved, literally, just these lines of code)

```
# This is in R. It runs k-means, with k=3, on the first two columns.
kmi <- kmeans(iris[,1:2],3)
plot(iris[,1:2], col=kmi$cluster)
```

[image]

In other words, you can just PRETEND it has two dimensions, and you still see clusters.

If I may, I'd like to give a broader suggestion though -- this is exactly the kind of thing that, if you're going to get into ML (and I hope you do!) you should try to puzzle out on your own. Need 2d data? Create 2d data! I'm sure your programming is good enough for that. That way you can actually test the real limits of the algorithms, as well. Some will work well on SOME data, some won't. Try k-means on two long, skinny, parallel clusters!

And of course feel free to come back as you make your experiments.